# Python split regex matches into two variables

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to split a re.findall match into two variables - one for the date and one for the time - but i can't find a way to split the list up somehow. Any help appreciated!

```
txt = "created_at': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 17, 11, 38, 26, tzinfo"
x = re.findall("datetime.datetime\((.+?)\, (.+?)\, (.+?)\, (.+?)\, (.+?)\, (.+?)\, tzinfo", txt)
print(x)
print(x[0:4])
```

This is the results I get

```
[('2023', '1', '17', '11', '38', '26')]
[('2023', '1', '17', '11', '38', '26')]
```

It seems like the re.findall doesn't create a list with each find but just puts it all into one entry. The first 3 numbers are the date, the last 3 the time. I really don't know how to approach this without being able to grab each item individually.

Comment: Have you tried `x[0][0:3]` ?

Comment: @NickODell thank you! i didn't know that was possible it worked immediately, thanks so much!!

Comment: Your regex is matched only once in the string, so there is only one tuple in the result list. But you can access to the substrings matched by the groups stored in the tuple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to extract the required fields for each match.

```py
res = [o[:4] for o in x]
```